# JPA Criteria API: Multiple condition on LEFT JOIN

Tags: jpa, left-join, criteria-api

I have a join reference like following for which the first join expression is constructed by the JPA API automatically.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> c = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Demand> demands = c.from(Demand.class);
Join<Demand, Metadata> joinMetadata = demands.join("metadatas", JoinType.LEFT);
```

but, I would like to add an aditional condition to my joinMetadata like Metadata.type="AFFECTATION_KEY" but I don't know how.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## JPA

JPA 2.0 always joins by the mapping join columns only, as it does not support an ON clause. JPA 2.1 on the other hand does support this:

```
... 
Join<Demand, Metadata> joinMetadata = demands.join("metadatas", JoinType.LEFT);
joinMetadata.on(cb.equal(joinMetadata.get("type"), "AFFECTATION_KEY"));
```

---

## EclipseLink

EclipseLink 2.4 has support for an ON clause,

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON

It is also possible through the Criteria API, using the EclipseLink *native* Expression API that provides `on` clause support,

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#JpaCriteriaBuilder_and_EclipseLink_Extensions

Answer (score 7):

And Hibernate's Criteria API version 3.6 supports it too:

```
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Tuple.class);

    c.createAlias("demands", "d")
    .createAlias("d.metadata", "m", 
        Criteria.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("m.type", "AFFECTATION_KEY"));
```

Or you may want Restrictions.eqProperty() for that last bit. Note the under-appreciated version of createAlias() with the fourth parameter. Here is a quote from the documentation

Parameters:

- associationPath - A dot-seperated property path
- alias - The alias to assign to the joined association (for later reference).
- joinType - The type of join to use.
- withClause - The criteria to be added to the join condition (ON clause)

[Hibernate API 3.6](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I can use only JPA Criteria API, can't reference hibernate API  even though hibernate is our JPA implementation.

Comment: And in JPQL, one could use the Hibernate-specific `WITH` to add *additional* join conditions, such as `from Demand d left join Metadata md with md.type="AFFECTATION_KEY"`.

Comment: JPQL does not support `WITH` - that is HQL you're referring to