# Select records which doesn't have specific records in joined table

Tags: java, mysql, many-to-many, criteria-api

Hi I'm trying to select records from one table which doesn't have records in connected many-to-many table with specific values.

I will explain on sample tables:

```
documentation:
id_documentation
irrelevant_data

user:
id_user
irrelevant_data


documentation_user:
id_documentation
id_user
role
```

What I want to achieve is to select every single documentation which doesn't have user in specific role. Any ideas?

The main problem is that I'm using java's CriteriaBuilder to create query so using subqueries is impossible (I think).

Comment: Maybe this... Is there any possibility to add more join condidions to be added in ON clause? For example:

select * from documentation d left join documentation_user du ON d.id_documentation = du.id_documentation AND du.role = 2;

Comment: Yes, starting from Hibernate 3.5.0 you can. see [this fix](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2308)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to achieve this with CriteriaBuilder?

    Root<Documentation> u = select.from(Documentation.class);
    Join<Documentation, DocumentationUser> dul = u.join("documentationUserCollection", JoinType.LEFT);

Answer (score 0):

Main problem does not exist - Criteria API do have [SubQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Subquery.html). Query itself selects instances of User and uses [not](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#not%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) [in](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#in%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) construct to limit results based to subquery. Subquery selects all users that are connected to document with specific role via DocumentationUser.

Comment: Better way is to left join documentation_user with additional on criteria and check if id_user is null: select * from documentation d left join documentation_user du on d.id_documentation = du.id_documentation and du.role = 2 where du.id_user is null;

Comment: But still I don't know how to add additional condition to join in CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: There is no possibility to add additional join conditions in Criteria API.

Comment: Could you please tell me how? Can't find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add restrictions on your left join using: `createAlias(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion)` method, see [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29).

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092067/1613867) answer for an example on how to use the left join with a criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (code not tested):

```
CriteriaQuery<Documentation> cq = cb.createQuery(Documentation.class);
Root<Documentation> u = cq.from(Documentation.class);
Subquery<Integer> sq = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<User> su = sq.from(User.class);
sq.select(su.get("id_user"));
Join<User, DocumentationUser> du = su.join("documentationUserCollection");
sq.where(cb.equals(du.get("role"), "mySpecificRole"));
cq.where(cb.not(cb.in(u.get("id_user")).value(sq)));
```

See also [this useful answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions).