# CriteriaBuilder: join one-to-many with ON clause

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

Suppose you the following OneToMany relationships: `School->Student->ScientificWork`. Now you want to select all Schools that have Student with name 'John' and his scientific job is called 'Black Holes'.

I do it like the following, but for some reason it retrurns me all possible schools.

```
public static Specification<School> spec() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        final SetJoin<School, Student> studs = root.joinSet("students", JoinType.LEFT);
        final SetJoin<Student, ScientificWork> works = root.joinSet("works", JoinType.LEFT);
        return cb.and(
                cb.equal(studs.get(Student_.name), 'John'),
                cb.equal(nodes.get(ScientificWork_.name), 'Black Holes')
        );
    };
}
```

### Update

After finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990141/how-to-make-a-criteriabuilder-join-with-a-custom-on-condition/37993919#37993919) I tried the following, but with the same result (it returns me all Schools instead of one):

```
public static Specification<School> spec() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        final SetJoin<School, Student> studs = root.joinSet("students", JoinType.LEFT);
        studs.on(cb.equal(studs.get(Student_.name), 'John'));
        final SetJoin<Student, ScientificWork> works = root.joinSet("works", JoinType.LEFT);          
        return cb.equal(nodes.get(ScientificWork_.name), 'Black Holes');
    };
}
```

Comment: Is this possible? Do someone need any additional details?

Comment: have you mistakenly used nodes instead of works?

Comment: This line ` final SetJoin<Student, ScientificWork> works = root.joinSet("works", JoinType.LEFT);`  should have been  ` final SetJoin<Student, ScientificWork> works = **studs**.joinSet("works", JoinType.LEFT);`  or it is a typo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Specification<School> spec() {
return (root, query, cb) -> {
    final Join<School, Student> studs = root.join("students", JoinType.LEFT);
    studs.on(cb.equal(studs.get(Student_.name), "John"));
    final Join<Student, ScientificWork> works = studs.join("works", JoinType.LEFT);          
    return cb.equal(works.get(ScientificWork_.name), "Black Holes");
};
```

}

I used **join** instead of **joinSet** and put `**works**.get(ScientificWork_.name)` instead of `**nodes**.get(ScientificWork_.name)`