# Customize JPA CriteriaQuery's on-clause

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, on-clause

Is there a way to further restrict a join by adding some expressions? With plain sql i write:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(i.id) invoice_count
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.customer_id = c.id
    AND i.creation_time >= '2012-01-01' -- <= extra restriction
    AND i.creation_time < '2013-01-01' -- <= extra restriction
GROUP BY c.id
```

I haven't found a way to implement this with JPA 2.0 CriteriaQuery.

**Update:** As requested my (simplified) code so far (without the extra restriction):

```
CriteriaQuery<CustomerAndInvoiceCount> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CustomerAndInvoiceCount.class);

Root<Customer> customer = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
ListJoin<Customer, Invoice> invoices = customer.join(Customer_.invoices, JoinType.LEFT);

criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(
        CustomerAndInvoiceCount.class,
        customer,
        criteriaBuilder.count(invoices)));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(customer);
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have added some Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the criteria predicates without worrying if they are part of the ON clause or the WHERE clause.

Comment: There is a difference: If i add the predicates to the WHERE clause, i lose customers if they don't have any invoices for the specified date range.

Comment: SELECT c.*, COUNT(i.id) invoice_count
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN invoices i ON i.customer_id = c.id
WHERE i.creation_time >= '2012-01-01'
    AND i.creation_time < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY c.id;

Comment: This does not work because i want to retrieve **all** customers with their invoice count. Adding the predicate to the where clause returns customers with at least one invoice.

Comment: @mazatwork Are you using Eclipse or Hibernate? ON support is not standard yet. Personally, I would do this as a NamedNativeQuery but if you must use Criteria you will have to use vendor specific enhancements.

Comment: Here's a link that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081955/jpa-criteria-api-multiple-condition-on-left-join

Comment: We use Hibernate 4. It seems we have to wait for hibernate 5 which will implement JPA 2.1.

Comment: Also check this url: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2177735, it suggest the same but also provide option to use JPQL something like "from Customer c left join c.invoices c1 with c1.creationTime >= :dateParam"